# Can a two-node (one on each box) cluster provide uninterrupted services if one box is down?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my production environment, I have a two-node cluster (ES 2.2.0) and each node sits on a different physical box. Inside elasticsearch.yml, I have the following:

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

My question is: if one box is down, can the other node continues to function  normally to provide uninterrupted search services (index and search, write and read)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two nodes and each is master-eligible and you have `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2`, if the network goes down and the two nodes don't see each other for a while, you'll get into a [split brain situation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-node.html#split-brain) because each node will elect itself as a master.

However, with a setting of 2, you have two possible situations:

- if the non-master goes down, the other node will continue to function properly (since it is already master)
- if the master goes down, the other won't be able to elect itself as the master (since it will wait for a second master-eligible node to be visible).

For this reason, with only two nodes, you need to choose between the possibility of a split brain (with `minimum_master_nodes: 1`) or a potentially RED cluster (with `minimum_master_nodes: 2`). The best way to overcome this is to include a third master-only node and then `minimum_master_nodes: 2` would make sense.

Just try it out:

1. Start your cluster, bring down the master node, what happens?
2. Start your cluster, bring down the non-master node, what happens?

Comment: Val, thanks for your input. By "include a third master-only node", you mean a new physical box? Or 2 nodes on each box?

Comment: Val, what is the practically better configuration in my case? I have only two  physical boxes. Two virtual servers, one from each box, are used for ES. Four nodes? Or just one node?

Comment: With two physical boxes, most people go with a settings of 1, because the risk of split brain is more bearable than having a RED cluster. The minimal setup to increase stability is three physical boxes, each being master-eligible and `minimum_master_nodes: 2`.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of minimum master nodes is to maintain the stability of the cluster.

If you have only 2 nodes in cluster and with 2 minimum master nodes settings.

If you are setting minimum master as 2, the cluster will expect 2 nodes to be UP to serve the various search services.

If one node goes down in your 2 node cluster (which had 2 minimum master node settings), theoretically cluster will goes down.

Comment: @curious1 my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

First, this setting helps prevent split brains, the existence of two masters in a single cluster.
If you have two nodes, A setting of 1 will allow your cluster to function, but doesn’t protect against split brain. It is best to have a minimum of three nodes in situations.